# How can I find & replace text across multiple files inside text boxes?

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I would like to change text that repeats in .doc and .docx files.

I have this macro running at the moment:

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub BatchReplaceAll()
    
    Dim FirstLoop As Boolean
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim PathToUse As String
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Dim Response As Long
    
    PathToUse = "C:\Files\"
    
    'Error handler to handle error generated whenever
    'the FindReplace dialog is closed
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Close all open documents before beginning
    Documents.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges
    
    'Boolean expression to test whether first loop
    'This is used so that the FindReplace dialog will'only be displayed for the first document
    FirstLoop = True
    
    'Set the directory and type of file to batch process
    myFile = Dir$(PathToUse & "*.docx")
    
    While myFile <> ""
        'Open document
        Set myDoc = Documents.Open(PathToUse & myFile)
    
        If FirstLoop Then
            'Display dialog on first loop only
            Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Show
            FirstLoop = False
            Response = MsgBox("Do you want to process " & _
            "the rest of the files in this folder", vbYesNo)
            If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
        Else
    
            'On subsequent loops (files), a ReplaceAll is
            'executed with the original settings and without
            'displaying the dialog box again
    
            With Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
                .ReplaceAll = 1
                .Execute
            End With
    
        End If
    
        'Close the modified document after saving changes
        myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    
        'Next file in folder
        myFile = Dir$()
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

It does work if replacing simple text.

How can I search and replace inside Text Boxes?

**EDIT 1:**

I changed this:

```vb
With Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
    .ReplaceAll = 1
    .Execute
End With
```

To this:

```vb
With Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
    
    For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        With myStoryRange.Find
            .Text = "ORIGINAL_TEXT"
            .Replacement.Text = "MODIFIED_TEXT"
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
        Do While Not (myStoryRange.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set myStoryRange = myStoryRange.NextStoryRange
            With myStoryRange.Find
                .Text = "ORIGINAL_TEXT"
                .Replacement.Text = "MODIFIED_TEXT"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Loop
    Next myStoryRange
    
End With
```

The problems with this new code is that sometimes it skips text boxes and it is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, Word "Text Boxes" are known as a [TextFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194846.aspx) Object. This may be able to point you in the right direction:

```
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Shapes 
 With s.TextFrame 
 If .HasText Then MsgBox .TextRange.Text 
 End With 
Next
```

I will update my answer when I get more information on implementing it into your example.

Comment: I'm assuming if you put a clause to explicitly look for `TextFrame`s it will not skip them at all. The problem there is that it will further slow down your code, and ultimately your process. Every check you add into the loop creates more time inbetween iterations. I've never been known to be a good optimizer either, sad to say :(